# postgresql transpose rows an columns misery

Tags: sql, postgresql, transpose

I have gone through all of the similar topics and can't seem to solve my problem. I have a table like this:

```
id[PK]        key[PK]     value
--------------------------------
22            ingfs       east1
22            storage     stgeast1
23            ingfs       east2
23            storage     stgeast2
24            ingfs       east3
24            storage     stgeast3
```

I want to get:

```
ingfs   storage
----------------
east1   stgeast1
east2   stgeast2
east3   stgeast3
```

I have tried the pivot table example but don't seem to be able to get anything to work. Seems like this should be simple but I can't get my head wrapped around it. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

rjl

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    max(case when key = 'ingfs' then value end) as ingfs,
    max(case when key = 'storage' then value end) as storage
from Table1
group by id
order by 1, 2
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dd8e8/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you?

```
WITH i AS (
    SELECT id, 
            value 
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE key = 'ingfs'),
s AS (
    SELECT id, 
            value 
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE key = 'storage')
SELECT i.value AS ingfs, 
        s.value AS storage
    FROM i
    JOIN s on ( i.id = s.id ) ;
```